# Problemas compartiendo en redes sociales usando open graph

Tags: php, javascript, opengraph

He creado un blog desde cero y ahora estoy haciendo que puedan compartir la noticia tanto en Facebook como en Twitter.

Es algo que hice hace algún tiempo en un proyecto **y me funcionaba**, pero en este nueva página que he montado (en un nuevo servidor) **no carga ni la imagen ni el texto de la noticia** en lo que comparte.

Entiendo que con este código cargo la imagen y el texto que lleva la noticia:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $res['titulo']; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://depildiodo.com/ver-noticia.php?ID=<?php echo $idnot; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.depildiodo.com/images/noticias/<?php echo $res['foto']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $subject; ?>" />
```

Tengo este script para que los botones de compartir hagan su función:

```
  $(document).on('click', ".shared", function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var title = document.title;

    url = encodeURIComponent(url);
    title = encodeURIComponent(title);

    //Boton Facebook
    if($(this).hasClass('fb')){
      url = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+url+'&t='+title;
      window.open(url, '_blank');

    //Boton Twitter
    }else if($(this).hasClass('tt')){
      user = 'Depildiodo';//Nuestro usuario de twitter para mostrar como @user
      url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+title+'&url='+url+'&via='+user;

      window.open(url, '_blank');

    //Boton WhtsApp
    }else if($(this).hasClass('wa')){
      url = 'whatsapp://send?text="'+document.title+'" - "'+window.location.href+'"';

    //Boton correo electronico
    }else if($(this).hasClass('ce')){
      url = 'mailto:?subject='+title+'&body='+url;


    //Ningun boton valido
    }else return;

    //Abrimos la url

  });
```

Éste es el botón de Facebook:

```
<div class="shared-panel">
  <a target="_blank" class="shared fb" title="Facebook"></a>
  <a target="_blank" class="shared tt" title="Twitter"></a>
  <a  data-action='share/whatsapp/share' class="shared wa" title="WhatsApp"></a>
  <a class="shared ce" id="sml" title="Email"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías facilitarnos la URL para ver si se está generando correctamente?

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia he cambiado el código por uno que encontré pero me pasa los mismo. Te adjunto la URL, los botones están al final de la noticia `https://depildiodo.com/ver-noticia.php?ID=2`

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona? ¿Pulsar los botones o el resumen que generan al compartir? Por cierto, has olvidado eliminar las etiquetas html de la descripción (`og:description`).

Comment: Lo que necesito es que al compartir cargue la foto y descripción de la notica, eso es lo que no funciona, en la etiqueta `og:description` no es donde coge el texto para compartir???

Comment: Sí, pero no puede contener etiquetas HTML (por lo que veo que no has usado `htmlspecialchars()` correctamente). Echa un vistazo a https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/ El texto que aparece en grande es lo que contiene `og:title` y en texto pequeño lo que tiene `og:description`, todo con el mismo formato.

Comment: Además, recuerda que hay [cuatro campos **obligatorios**](http://ogp.me/#metadata) que son `og:title`, `og:type`, `og:image` y `og:url`.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, pero lo que no logro entender es esto que me dices `pero no puede contener etiquetas HTML (por lo que veo que no has usado htmlspecialchars() correctamente)` @OscarGarcia

Comment: El intercambio de información se está alargando demasiado. [Continuemos el tema en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94843/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-miguel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Corrigiendo los campos open graph

Tras corregir y agregar los [cuatro campos open graph obligatorios](http://ogp.me/#metadata) (`og:title`, `og:type`, `og:image` y `og:url`) solicité [durante la conversación del chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50662752#50662752) que comprobara los datos de depuración de la web de Facebook en la siguiente URL:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdepildiodo.com%2Fver-noticia.php%3FID%3D2

Observamos que la página nos mostraba, algo escondido, un mensaje de error de cURL que impedía que se obtuvieran los campos requeridos. Pudimos reproducir el error de la siguiente manera:

```
$ curl 'https://depildiodo.com/ver-noticia.php?ID=2'
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

### Problema con el certificado HTTPS

El principal problema por el que ni Facebook ni Twitter recogían la información correctamente era por un **error en la cadena de certificación** del certificado del servidor web.

Usando `openssl` vimos que el servidor entregaba únicamente un certificado:

```
$ openssl s_client -host depildiodo.com -port 443 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = *.depildiodo.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.depildiodo.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.depildiodo.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=Encryption Everywhere DV TLS CA - G1
....
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

Por lo que todo apuntaba a que faltaba una entidad certificadora intermedia (`Encryption Everywhere DV TLS CA - G1`) por agregar al certificado que entrega el servidor web.

De la [página web oficial de la entidad certificadora](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm) nos descargamos el certificado de la entidad intermedia y lo convertimos a PEM de la siguiente manera:

```
curl 'https://dl.cacerts.digicert.com/EncryptionEverywhereDVTLSCA-G1.crt' \
  > /etc/ssl/EncryptionEverywhereDVTLSCA-G1.crt
openssl x509 -inform der -in /etc/ssl/EncryptionEverywhereDVTLSCA-G1.crt \
  -out /etc/ssl/EncryptionEverywhereDVTLSCA-G1.pem
```

Luego generamos el certificado incluyendo a la cadena la entidad certificadora intermedia *después* del certificado expedido:

```
cat /etc/ssl/depildiodo.com_ssl_certificate.cer \
  /etc/ssl/EncryptionEverywhereDVTLSCA-G1.pem \
  > /etc/ssl/depildiodo.com_completo.cer
```

Al concatenar nos percatamos que no había separación entre el fin de un bloque y el comienzo del siguiente:

```
grep '\-\-\-' /etc/ssl/depildiodo.com_completo.cer
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
-----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Por lo que tuvimos que dividirlo con la siguiente instrucción:

```
sed -i 's#----------#-----\n-----#g' /etc/ssl/depildiodo.com_completo.cer
```

Quedando ahora correctamente separado:

```
grep '\-\-\-' /etc/ssl/depildiodo.com_completo.cer
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Cambiamos el certificado que carga el servidor web (un nginx) de la siguiente manera:

```
; Comentamos el antiguo certificado
; ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/depildiodo.com_ssl_certificate.cer;
; Dejamos configurado el nuevo con la entidad certificadora intermedia
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/depildiodo.com_completo.cer;
```

Tras reiniciar el servidor nginx todo debería funcionar correctamente y tanto Facebook como Twitter deberían obtener la información de open graph sin problemas.

Comment: creo que debes cambiar la pregunta, seria interesante para otros usuarios saber que se necesitan los certificados ssl para  consultar los servicios de facebook y/o twitter

Comment: Mañana intentaré editar la pregunta para que refleje mejor lo que le ocurría y mejorar el seo para otra gente que tenga el mismo problema.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia tengo el mismo problema de nuevo pero con algunos navegadores que me dan aviso de peligro por el SSL, pero releyendo lo que pones no se muy bien como hacerlo

Comment: Hola @Miguel. ¿Es tu propio servidor en un PC tuyo, VPS o similar o, en cambio, has contratado alojamiento compartido con otra empresa? ¿Tienes un certificado contratado, gratuito o autogenerado?

Comment: Hola Oscar tengo con Ionos un servidor propio. Y ellos me dan los certificados, como con los otros que hicimos. Pero aqui el problema me viene cuando pongo las https://www.dominio.es   me dice que pertenece a otro de mis dominios

Comment: ¿Entoces es otro dominio virtual en el mismo servidor que la última vez? Hoy no puedo ayudarte, pero mañana por la mañana abrimos un chat y lo revisamos en él, ¿Vale?

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia al final no miramos nada, no se si podemos verlo, ya que tengo ya el blog activado, pero no me carga el opengraph, me puedes ayudar

Comment: Buenos días @Miguel. [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107022/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-miguel).

Answer (score 2):

Probablemente tengas tu código bien, pero tienes un problema con el certificado digital, concretamente con la cadena de certificado, y está relacionado con que el certificado sea de tipo wildcard (*.depildiodo.com). A mí me ocurrió algo parecido. Si entras en la siguiente URL puedes comprobar el error:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdepildiodo.com%2Fver-noticia.php%3FID%3D1

[image: Depurador de contenido compartido - Facebook para desarrolladores]

Puedes comprobar los problemas con el certificado en múltiples sitios:

[SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=depildiodo.com&latest)
[SSLShopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=depildiodo.com)

[image: Chain issues - Incomplete]

Comment: Muchas gracias @Pavel y bienvenido a la comunidad. No deberías redactar una respuesta si no soluciona el problema planteado. En su lugar deberías haber escrito un comentario, aunque aún no tienes reputación suficiente para hacerlo deberías tener paciencia hasta entonces. Además, si hubieras entrado en la sala de chat hubieras averiguado que llegamos a esa conclusión y hemos dedicado bastante tiempo y esfuerzo en arreglarlo.

Comment: No tenía ni idea que existían comentarios y respuestas. Tampoco el chat. Gracias por la aclaración.